# Failed to register library Extension-Name jenkins error on weblogic server

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, weblogic12c

I tried to a deployment with Jenkins. But I got an error in web logic server 12.1.3. I configured `"plugin-configuration.xsd"` file in Jenkins web logic plugin. Also I configured Web logic Deployment Plugin parameters in Jenkins web interface.

```
additional classpath: C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\server\lib\wlthint3client.jar

Configuration file: myPath\.jenkins\plugins\weblogic-deployer-plugin\config\plugin-configuration.xsd
```

How can I solve this?

In addition, my config.xsd file is that;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns="http://org.jenkinsci.plugins/WeblogicDeploymentPlugin"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://org.jenkinsci.plugins/WeblogicDeploymentPlugin plugin-configuration.xsd"> 
<weblogic-targets>
    <weblogic-target>
        <name>weblogic_local_server</name>
        <host>127.0.0.1</host>
        <port>7001</port>
        <login>admin</login>
        <password>admin</password>
        <authMode>BY_LOGIN</authMode>
    </weblogic-target>
</weblogic-targets>
</config>
```

The error is here:

```
<BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application "jenkins [,LibImplVersion=2.60.3]" due to error weblogic.application.library.LibraryDeploymentException: [J2EE:160144]Failed to register library Extension-Name: jenkins, Implementation-Version: 2.60.3: Library cannot have Implementation-Version set, without also specifying its Specification-Version
weblogic.application.library.LibraryDeploymentException: [J2EE:160144]Failed to register library Extension-Name: jenkins, Implementation-Version: 2.60.3: Library cannot have Implementation-Version set, without also specifying its Specification-Version
    at weblogic.application.internal.library.LibraryDeployment.prepare(LibraryDeployment.java:66)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:61)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppDeployment.prepare(AppDeployment.java:155)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doPrepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:39)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.prepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:191)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$1.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:21)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.prepare(ConfiguredDeployments.java:165)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:122)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:210)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:118)
    at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1017)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:388)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:430)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:606)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:77)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:231)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:254)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:413)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:753)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that; Wblogic Deployment Plugin additional classpath parameter was wrong. It must be "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.jar".

```
java -cp C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar weblogic.Deployer -adminurl t3://localhost:7001 -username admin -password q1w2e3r4 -deploy -name sample -targets AdminServer -source C:\sample.war
```